# How to resolve the ambiguity in the Boy or Girl paradox?

Tags: probability, paradox, puzzle

Specifically, I was reading [this article](https://everything.explained.today/Boy_or_Girl_paradox/), which discusses this wording of the question:

> Consider a family with two children. Given that one of the children is a boy, what is the probability that both children are boys?

and says

> In this formulation the ambiguity is most obviously present, because it is not clear whether we are allowed to assume that a specific child is a boy, leaving the other child uncertain, or whether it should be interpreted in the same way as "at least one boy".

It's not clear to me what, "specific child" is meant to mean in this context.
My thought was that it referred to calculating the probability that "exactly one" child is a boy, as opposed to the "at least one child is a boy" interpretation, but that can't be right, since, if we're given that exactly one child is a boy and we know the first one is a boy, the probability the second one is a boy would be zero.  But the actual "competing" (for lack of a better word) probabilities are 1/2 and 1/3.

Additionally, if I try to come up with an equivalent problem in terms of coin flips I get still different probabilities.
e.g., "What's the probability the FIRST coin in a sequence of 2 coin flips is heads" (clearly 1/2) vs asking "What's the probability *at least one* of the coins in the sequence is sequence is heads?" (P(first coin is heads) + P(second coin is heads) - P(both are heads) = 1/2 + 1/2 - 1/4 = 3/4)

Where am I going wrong in my thinking here and how do I think about it correctly?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15055/in-a-family-with-two-children-what-are-the-chances-if-one-of-the-children-is-a and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/73593/learning-probability-bad-reasoning-conditional-and-unconditional

Comment: There's no paradox here, just ambiguity. We're giving a vague description of a "real life" situation, and you're supposed to turn that into a well defined probability space in which to express events and their probabilities. This is often hard or impossible to do, with the only possible conclusion being "some assumptions are missing". In this "boy and girl" problem, there is additional confusion: there are many very-subtly-different situations that would result in different probabilities, and it's easy to confuse one situation with the other, so it's easy to draw false conclusions.

Comment: It looks like a "paradox" when you transcribe the vague language into two incompatible probability spaces by silently making two incompatible extra assumptions, and don't even notice that these two spaces correspond to incompatible extra assumptions. Then you can draw inconsistent (and wrong) conclusions.

Comment: I believe that the correct path to the answer 3/4 for the question of at least one heads is not using addition as given. The correct math would be to start from unity and subtract the probability that both flips produce tails. 1 - (1/2 * 1/2) = 3/4. This formula works correctly when extending the question to "what is the probability of flipping a coin N times and getting at least one heads?" 1 - (1/2)**N

Answer (score 17, accepted):

"Given that one is a boy" is rather confusing wording, I've seen many more people confused over the question than over the answer.

Suppose that the two children are assigned labels: Child 1, and Child 2.

If we say a specific child is a boy, then we would say, for example, that Child 1 is a boy. The question is then whether Child 2 is a boy, given that Child 1 is a boy.

If we say that (at least) one child is a boy, then we would say that either Child 1 is a boy, or Child 2 is a boy (or both), but we don't know which. The question is then whether both children are boys, given that at least one of them is.

In terms of coins, this is the difference between $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{coin 2 is heads} \,|\, \textrm{coin 1 is heads})$ and $\mathbb{P}(\textrm{coin 1 is heads} \cap \textrm{coin 2 is heads} \,|\, \textrm{coin 1 is heads} \cup \textrm{coin 2 is heads})$.

Comment: +1 although there still might be some confusion in what it means to assign fixed labels to children we don't know anything about. To make it sound more natural, it's more common to use "older child" and "younger child" as labels.

Comment: "Suppose that the two children are assigned *labels*:"  This is what made it click for me.  It's not about "exactly one" vs "at least one" but about _distinguishable_ vs _indistinguishable_ events, yes? It's like the distinction in the probability distributions for fermions (indistinguishable particles) and bosons (distinguishable particles).  And THAT distinction is the reason for the Pauli exclusion principle, which is the reason atoms other than hydrogen can exist.  Sheesh, I did NOT expect that this simple probability puzzle would be related to something so profound in physics.

Answer (score 35):

This is a language problem, not a paradox. The problem is how we should interpret

> Consider a family with two children. Given that one of the children is a boy, ...

Assume, we have 4 equally likely possibilities

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 boy    boy
 girl   girl
 girl   boy
```

Interpretation 1:

Given that one of the children (e.g. the first) is a boy

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 boy    boy
```

Then the probability for both children being a boy is 1/2

Interpretation 2:

Given that one of the children is a boy (ie. a boy is among the first and/or the second)

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 boy    boy
 girl   boy
```

Then the probability for both children being a boy is 1/3.

Interpretation 3:

Given that one of the children is a boy (ie. the number of boys is one)

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 girl   boy
```

Then the probability for both children being a boy is 0/2.

---

> It's not clear to me what, "specific child" is meant to mean in this context

This refers to the first interpretation.

Comment: The last one is clearly a language issue. If someone has two boys, and was asked how many boys they have, them answering "I have one boy" is clearly wrong, even though the set of two boys include one boy, but nobody will actually answer like that. It's like saying "Do you have a dollar? No, I have two." It is just stupid but not necessarily wrong.

Comment: If someone has two children, and I say: "I'll give you ten dollars if you say that you have at least one boy. I'll give you 100 dollars if you say that you have two boys. I'll check and I'll shoot you if you lied". If they say "I have at least one boy" then two boys are very, very unlikely.

Comment: @gnasher729 there are all sorts of contexts that can help to understand the intended interpretation. The situation that you sketch would lead to the third interpretation.

Comment: @Nelson "In Major League Baseball (MLB), the 30–30 club is the group of batters who have collected thirty home runs and thirty stolen bases in a single season." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/30%E2%80%9330_club Someone with 35 home runs and 35 stolen bases would be in the club. Someone with 2 boys also has one boy.

Comment: While many people would prefer the word "paradox" to refer strictly to self-contradictory logical propositions (something like that, anyway), in practice its meaning [has expanded quite a bit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppX7Qjbe6BM).

Answer (score -2):

I believe the other answers so far are confusing probability and arrangement.

Let's say I move into a new house and see a boy playing in the neighbour's yard. Later I meet one of the neighbours and she says "I have two children". What are the chances that they are both boys (making the assumption the one I saw is hers)?

1/2. I have seen a boy. There is one other child. That child is either a boy or a girl, with equal probability. It doesn't matter whether the boy I saw is the younger or elder child, the probability is the same for the other child.

With respect to the suggestion that the probability is 1/3 because the neighbour could have:

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 boy    boy
 girl   boy
```

This is dealing in arrangements of the kids, not probability, and is ignoring an important factor. Yes, there are three visible arrangements of kids that would satisfy the known facts, except that since we don't know if the boy seen is the elder or younger, what we really have is four arrangements, and still a 50/50 chance for two boys:

```
 1st    2nd  
 boy    girl
 boy seen    boy
 boy    boy seen
 girl   boy
```

The net effect is that even if I don't know which one is definitely a boy, the other child can only be a girl or a boy and that is always and only a 1/2 probability (ignoring any biological weighting that girls may represent 51% of births or whatever the reality is).

Comment: This is the kind of erroneous logic that leads people to call the problem a paradox! Your assertion "...either a boy or a girl, with equal probability" is unsupported.  It amounts to an application of Laplace's principle of insufficient reason, which is not justified by the axioms of probability.

Comment: @whuber If you have a third option for the other child I'll be intrigued to hear it. If you have an argument for why the unknown child doesn't have an equal probability you need to say so. My logic is sound. 
There is no paradox here. Every child has a 1/2 chance of being a boy or girl. You just have to do your accounting clearly, as I have done above.

Comment: The probabilities don't rest on how many different types of children there are.  But this thread is not about the paradox itself, which you can find explained in many places on the Web and even (I believe) here on CV, where correct analyses are given.

Comment: @whuber, I mean it _is_ a paradox in the sense that the answer is counterintuitive to most people, even after they've seen the logic of the solution.