# Probability of the sex of twins

Tags: probability

I am expecting DCDA twins (90% probability of being fraternal rather than identical)
Initial stats for fraternal twins is 25% BB, 25% GG and 50% mixed sex (BG + GB)
A blood test confirmed the presence of at least one Y chromosome thereby ruling out GG. Is the remaining chance of mixed sex twins now 66.6% or is it 50% as it’s only one baby’s sex that is unknown?

Comment: This is a nicely stated version of the Boy or Girl Paradox. This wiki has all the answers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boy_or_Girl_paradox

Comment: Also see here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/620515/how-to-resolve-the-ambiguity-in-the-boy-or-girl-paradox basically, it has to do with how ambiguously you word the "given a child is a boy". In this case, presence of a y-chromosome in gestating twins means you can only exclude GG.